# Adjusting BBcode parser to note parse smileys in URLs?

Tags: php, regex, bbcode

I am wondering how I would go about adjusting my BBcode parser to not parse smileys within URLs?

Here is my parser:

```
    $smilies = array(   
"><" => '<img src="/jscripts/sce/emoticons/angry.png" alt="" />',
":'(" => '<img src="/jscripts/sce/emoticons/cry.png" alt="" />',
":S" => '<img src="/jscripts/sce/emoticons/dizzy.png" alt="" />',
":D" => '<img src="/jscripts/sce/emoticons/grin.png" alt="" />',
"^_^" => '<img src="/jscripts/sce/emoticons/happy.png" alt="" />',
"<3" => '<img src="/jscripts/sce/emoticons/heart.png" alt="" />',
":huh:" => '<img src="/jscripts/sce/emoticons/huh.png" alt="" />',
":|" => '<img src="/jscripts/sce/emoticons/pouty.png" alt="" />',
":(" => '<img src="/jscripts/sce/emoticons/sad.png" alt=""/>',
":O" => '<img src="/jscripts/sce/emoticons/shocked.png" alt="" />',
":sick:" => '<img src="/jscripts/sce/emoticons/sick.png" alt="" />',
":)" => '<img src="/jscripts/sce/emoticons/smile.png" alt="" />',
":P" => '<img src="/jscripts/sce/emoticons/tongue.png" alt="" />',
":S" => '<img src="/jscripts/sce/emoticons/unsure.png" alt="" />',
":woot:" => '<img src="/jscripts/sce/emoticons/w00t.png" alt="" />',
":whistle:" => '<img src="/jscripts/sce/emoticons/whistle.png" alt="" />',
";)" => '<img src="/jscripts/sce/emoticons/wink.png" alt="" />',
":wub:" => '<img src="/jscripts/sce/emoticons/wub.png" alt="" />'
);

$body = str_replace( array_keys( $smilies ), array_values( $smilies ), $body );
```

The problem has come up as someone put in a link of

```
http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/User:Soeb
```

Which then tried to put in a ":S" smiley image?

Comment: How can you differentiate a smilie `:S` and a normal `:S`?

Comment: I don't which is where the problem comes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) instead of `str_replace()` and check if smiley is bounded by a space *(or start of string, or end of string)*

Code:

```
$smilies = array(   
"/( |^)><( |$)/" => ' <img src="/jscripts/sce/emoticons/angry.png" alt="" /> ',
"/( |^):'\(( |$)/" => ' <img src="/jscripts/sce/emoticons/cry.png" alt="" /> ',
"/( |^):S( |$)/" => ' <img src="/jscripts/sce/emoticons/dizzy.png" alt="" /> ',
"/( |^):D( |$)/" => ' <img src="/jscripts/sce/emoticons/grin.png" alt="" /> ',
"/( |^)\^_\^( |$)/" => ' <img src="/jscripts/sce/emoticons/happy.png" alt="" /> ',
"/( |^)<3( |$)/" => ' <img src="/jscripts/sce/emoticons/heart.png" alt="" /> ',
"/( |^):huh:( |$)/" => ' <img src="/jscripts/sce/emoticons/huh.png" alt="" /> ',
"/( |^):\|( |$)/" => ' <img src="/jscripts/sce/emoticons/pouty.png" alt="" /> ',
"/( |^):\(( |$)/" => ' <img src="/jscripts/sce/emoticons/sad.png" alt=""/> ',
"/( |^):O( |$)/" => ' <img src="/jscripts/sce/emoticons/shocked.png" alt="" /> ',
"/( |^):sick:( |$)/" => ' <img src="/jscripts/sce/emoticons/sick.png" alt="" /> ',
"/( |^):\)( |$)/" => ' <img src="/jscripts/sce/emoticons/smile.png" alt="" /> ',
"/( |^):P( |$)/" => ' <img src="/jscripts/sce/emoticons/tongue.png" alt="" /> ',
"/( |^):S( |$)/" => ' <img src="/jscripts/sce/emoticons/unsure.png" alt="" /> ',
"/( |^):woot:( |$)/" => ' <img src="/jscripts/sce/emoticons/w00t.png" alt="" /> ',
"/( |^):whistle:( |$)/" => ' <img src="/jscripts/sce/emoticons/whistle.png" alt="" /> ',
"/( |^);\)( |$)/" => ' <img src="/jscripts/sce/emoticons/wink.png" alt="" /> ',
"/( |^):wub:( |$)/" => ' <img src="/jscripts/sce/emoticons/wub.png" alt="" /> '
);

$body=preg_replace( array_keys($smilies), array_values($smilies), $body );
```

See it in action [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/0Zy7HU).